# What is the Skill Elements Only quest?

Tags: naruto-blazing

For the 3 mission objectives on some of the missions, one of them says "Skill Elements Only"

I'm wondering what this means and how do I complete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been updated in a newer version to be more descriptive. All of these types of quests require you to have a team of only the required type on your team. This includes the ninja on your bench.